# Changing the order of integration?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

For example if I have:

$$\int_0^1 \int_1^2 \int_0^3 f(x,y,z) \space  dx \space dy \space  dz $$

If I want to change the order of integration e.g. to $( dz \space dy \space dx )$

$$\int_0^3 \int_1^2 \int_0^1 f(x,y,z) \space  dz \space dy \space  dx $$

Would it be just a matter of re-writing and switching the integral? Will I get the same answer?

Comment: Yes, this is called an iterated integral

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can change the order or integration without changing the answer. This is true because of [Fubini's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem), which (when integrating over two variables), states
$$\int_{y_a}^{y_b}\int_{x_a}^{x_b} f(x,y)\,\mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}x=\int_{x_a}^{x_b}\int_{y_a}^{y_b}f(x,y)\,\mathrm{d}y\,\mathrm{d}x$$
You can change the order of integration for any number of variables, so long as you keep the bounds in the right order.

However, this won't necessarily work if the bounds are functions of one or more variables.

Comment: Does this still work in case of surface integrals when say the limit of $y$ is in form of $x$? i.e. Say $x$ is from $0$ to $2$ and $y$ is from $0$ to $2-x$?

Comment: @user963241 No, it won't work there. Although if you knew a relation between $y$ and $x$, then you might be able to change the bounds in certain cases using that relationship.